# PHP Email form not sending all Fields

Tags: php, forms, email, submit

When I submit the form I am receiving the last_name and the email fields but not hte first_name.  Driving me crazy!  If anyone can take a quick look at this and let me know why I would greatly appreciate it.  I am a beginner with PHP.  Thanks!!

HTML:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
        <div class="email_section_details"> <span class="msg_icon"><img src="common/images/msg_icon.png" alt="" /></span>
          <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
            <label for="first_name"><strong>First</strong>NAME:</label>
              <span class="input_bg">
              <input name="first_name" type="text" value="" />
              </span> </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="email"><strong>EMAIL</strong>ADDRESS:</label>
              <span class="input_bg">
              <input name="email" type="text" value="" />
              </span> </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="last_name"><strong>LAST</strong>NAME:</label>
              <span class="input_bg">
              <input name="last_name" type="text" value="" />
              </span> </div>
            <input type="image" src="common/images/submit_btn.png" class="submit_btn" />
        </div>
          </form>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "#";
    $email_subject = "Email Update Sign-up Request from #";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']))


    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. Please use your "Back Button" to return to the Home Page

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: When you do print_r($_POST); what you get?

Comment: Sorry, total newb here. Where would I place that?

Comment: before: 
`if(isset($_POST['email']))`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this code:

```
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']))


$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
```

It's an if statement with no code following, so it's picking up the next line where you assign $first_name.  So that never gets executed.  It's equivalent to this:

```
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
}

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
```

On a related note, in general, this code is fairly messy with inconsistent levels of indents, etc.  I know it seems trivial and pedantic, but if you spend a little more time writing cleaner code, you will find it easier to troubleshoot bugs like this (as will other people).

Comment: Fantastic, that solved it.  Thank you!  I will definitely clean up the code in the future---in a huge rush today.  Thanks Again